# Is Azure ACL available for cloud service?

Tags: azure, cloud, acl, firewall

As far as I know, I have two ways to apply IP address restrictions for cloud service.

1. Add startup task on the web role to use netsh command to modify the windows firewall
2. Sandrino Di Mattia has a good solution [here](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/apply-ip-address-restrictions-to-your-windows-azure-cloud-services/), which could config the firewall via cloud service configuration.

Recently Azure releases ACL support for VM endpoint. Is there the same way to apply ACL for cloud service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure website IP restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884098/azure-website-ip-restriction)

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent Azure SDK (2.3) ACL's have been included as part of Cloud Services (Web/Worker Roles/PaaS).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2014/04/22/windows-azure-paas-acls-are-here.aspx