# Azure website IP restriction

Tags: azure, ip, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I have an Azure website which I only use for development and testing, therefore I want to restrict access to it for everyone but myself.
According to this [blog article](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/12/09/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/) this is now offically supported, so I tried adding this to my web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="1.2.3.4" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

For the ipAddress attribute I have to use the IP address of my internet connection right? So I went to http://www.whatismyip.com/ and copied the address, but now my website is simply blocking all requests, the allow rule has no effect.

Did I miss something?

**UPDATE:** The log files revealed that the IPs seen by the web server are not those of the actual clients, but of a proxy in between (Cloudflare). So I tried to solve this by adding `enableProxyMode="true"`, unfortunately this does not fix my issue. Any ideas of how to get IP restrictions to work with Cloudflare?

Comment: You are correct on the ipAddress attribute.  Are you certain this is exactly what is in your web.config?  The configuration as you have it (changed for my IP) works just fine.  If this configuration is correct, then go into the CONFIGURE page for your site and turn on WEB SERVER LOGGING-FILE SYSTEM.  Then, try hitting your site again and look into the logs to see what the client IP is that's getting logged.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will check my log files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in case someone is trying to setup IP restrictions with Cloudflare: the solution is to not only add your IP to the whitelist, but also all the Cloudflare IPs (taken from [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips)).

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity enableProxyMode="true" allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
            <!-- YOUR IP -->
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="1.2.3.4" />
            <!-- CLOUDFLARE -->
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="199.27.128.0" subnetMask="255.255.248.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="173.245.48.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.21.244.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.22.200.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.31.4.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="141.101.64.0" subnetMask="255.255.192.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="108.162.192.0" subnetMask="255.255.192.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="190.93.240.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="188.114.96.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="197.234.240.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="198.41.128.0" subnetMask="255.255.128.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="162.158.0.0" subnetMask="255.254.0.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="104.16.0.0" subnetMask="255.240.0.0" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Isn't the website accessible to the public again though?  That is, assuming all traffic hits the site via Cloudflare, how does this block anyone else?

Comment: Cloudflare adds a `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header with the IP of the original client and `enableProxyMode="true"` tells the webserver to also check this header for valid IPs.

Comment: To my great surprise, this actually works pretty well. As long as you enableProxyMode then it seems to pick up the CF IPs as proxy headers only, disallowing them actual access but using them to figure out the original request IP. I'll post an updated IP list as a separate answer (the suggested edit queue is full already).

Comment: This is great - thank you! Super important to do this if you're using CloudFlare Access.

Answer (score 0):

Not intended as a full answer, just posting a slightly updated list of CloudFlare IPs in useful copy/paste format. See the accepted answer for usage.

```
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.21.244.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.22.200.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.31.4.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="104.16.0.0" subnetMask="255.240.0.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="108.162.192.0" subnetMask="255.255.192.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="131.0.72.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="141.101.64.0" subnetMask="255.255.192.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="162.158.0.0" subnetMask="255.254.0.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="172.64.0.0" subnetMask="255.248.0.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="173.245.48.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="188.114.96.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="190.93.240.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="197.234.240.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="198.41.128.0" subnetMask="255.255.128.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="199.27.128.0" subnetMask="255.255.248.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the current list of Cloudflare IPs:

```
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
            <!-- CLOUDFLARE -->
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.21.244.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.22.200.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="103.31.4.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="104.16.0.0" subnetMask="255.248.0.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="104.24.0.0" subnetMask="255.252.0.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="108.162.192.0" subnetMask="255.255.192.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="131.0.72.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="141.101.64.0" subnetMask="255.255.192.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="162.158.0.0" subnetMask="255.254.0.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="172.64.0.0" subnetMask="255.248.0.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="173.245.48.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="188.114.96.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="190.93.240.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="197.234.240.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" />
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="198.41.128.0" subnetMask="255.255.128.0" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
```

Answer (score -2):

Since Azure SDK 2.3 it's possible to use Access Control List (ACL) to apply IP restrictions for your cloud services.

Just add the ACL to your **ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg**:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <AccessControls>
        <AccessControl name="test">
            <Rule action="permit" description="test" order="100" remoteSubnet="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32" />
            <Rule action="deny" description="test" order="200" remoteSubnet="0.0.0.0/0" />
        </AccessControl>
    </AccessControls>
    <EndpointAcls>
        <EndpointAcl role="WebRoleName" endPoint="Endpoint1" accessControl="test" />
    </EndpointAcls>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

Comment: This applies for Cloud Services but not for Azure Web Apps