# restricting ip addresses for Azure website blocks me from accessing my localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, ip-address

I'm calling this code in my config file to block all ip addresses except mine when I publish my site to Azure.

```
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="98.214.211.202" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>
  </ipSecurity>  
</security>
```

And this works to block everyone except me when I publish my site to Azure, but when I launch the site from localhost to debug, it seems to block me on my dev machine.

What Ip address would I need to include in the allowed addresses to unblock my dev (localhost) machine?

I tried the '127.0.0.1' with no luck

Comment: Have you considered using a transform for your web.config when you publish to Azure, and leaving the IP restriction out of your web.config for development on your localhost?

Comment: Have you tried adding IP restrictions through the Web App network configuration?

Comment: I hadn't but now I will try!! thanks

Comment: Hi Rob. I see there are two config files debug and release. Do I just put the code into the release file??

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884098

Comment: why do you post the same question again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988142

Answer (score 2):

Rather than modifying your web.config locally, try adding an IP restriction via the Web App network configuration:

[image]

Now you can add specific IP addresses (or ranges):

[image]

Note: This isn't supported with **free** or **shared** tiers.